# how the data can be updated if I am using java RandomAccessFile

Tags: java

I have this code for modify  data in file using  RandomAccessFile.
but it cannot work.

```
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("enter search id");
    String search = sc.next().toLowerCase();

    try {
    file = new RandomAccessFile(new File("HallFile.txt"), "rw");
    long FileSize = file.length();
    file.seek(0);
    long numberOfRecords = FileSize / RECORD;
    for (int j = 0; j < numberOfRecords; j++) {


            hall_id= file.readInt();
            floorNo= file.readInt();
            area= file.readInt();
            capacity= file.readInt();
            rent= file.readInt();
            dimonssion= file.readInt();

            char temp = '\0';

            for(int i=0; i< 20; i++){
                temp = file.readChar();
                if(temp == '\0') continue;
                hall_type += temp;
            }
            for(int i=0; i< 20; i++){
                temp = file.readChar();
                if(temp == '\0') continue;
                seat_style += temp;
            }
            for(int i=0; i< 20; i++){
                temp = file.readChar();
                if(temp == '\0') continue;
                facilities += temp;

           Integer m = hall_id;
         if(search.equals(m.toString()))
         {

       file.seek(RECORD*j+144);

       System.out.println("New Floor NO: ");
       floorNo= sc.nextInt();
       file.write(floorNo);
       System.out.println("Hall area: ");
       area= sc.nextInt();
       file.write(area); 
       System.out.println("Hall capacity: ");
       capacity= sc.nextInt();
       file.write(capacity); 
       System.out.println("Hall rent per day: ");
       rent= sc.nextInt();
       file.write(rent);
       System.out.println("Hall Type: ");
       hall_type= sc.next().toLowerCase();
       file.writeUTF(hall_type); 
       System.out.println("Hall Style: ");
       seat_style= sc.next().toLowerCase();
       file.writeUTF(seat_style); 
       System.out.println("Hall Facilities: ");
       facilities= sc.next().toLowerCase();
       file.writeUTF(facilities); 
       System.out.println("Hall Dimonssion: ");
       dimonssion= sc.nextInt();
       file.write(dimonssion); 
       System.out.println("Saved successfully.");

                }
            }
            file.close();

        }} catch (IOException e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
                        System.out.println("error");
 }
```

Comment: these are the variables                                           int hall_id, floorNo, area, capacity, rent,dimonssion, lenght, width;
     
 String hall_type, seat_style, facilities;                                       and the final int RECORD is 144

Comment: There should be an `Edit` button below the question where you can add information or reformat it. Also: what in your code is not working as expected? What happens? What should happen? In case of errors, please add the exception stacktrace to your question.

Comment: This code shows the data that will add into file and I want to edit these data but I don't have idea about that.

Comment: what means "edit the data"? Where is that data that you want to edit? How do you want to edit it? I can see what the code does but I don't understand your question.

Comment: edit data means modify the data. the data in HallFile. I want to modify the saved data to new data, for example, area is 23c I want to modify it to 243b.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the data in to a set of variables, updating them as required (you can prompt the current value of each to the user & ask for a new value, with Enter defaulting to unchanged), then writing the updated values out again.

If you know what values you want to write & what record-index in the file, you can also seek there and directly overwrite.

But normally "change" implies knowing what you're changing.

Comment: I prompt the current value to the user but when I ask for new value, it cannot display that.

Comment: Show the work & code you've done -- either in this question, or a separate (more specific) one. I can't see any of the supposed code you're talking about.

Comment: Use the same method to write the changed record, as you do the original. This code is completely different -- you're calling writeUTF() where in your reading code, you were reading 20-byte fixed-width strings. Don't bring me such nonsense. I also don't see why you add 144 to the seek position. Your loop should also be clean -- with definite logic & exit conditions. This is anything but. Write some clean & proper code please.

Comment: That is cool,but for the data which are hall_type, seat_style and facilities cannot be updated and when the user enter the new data, it only add it to the current data.

Comment: Your READ and WRITE methods need to exactly match in data format. The business rules as to when & what data can be changed are irrelevant to that. Ideally, your write() and read() would be methods receiving/ returning a parameter of type Hall, with the data members as properties inside it. Since I have helped you & answered your question it would be expected for you to accept my answer now. Thanks.